# Best practices for drag and drop in Cocoa Touch

Tags: cocoa-touch, drag-and-drop, swift2

I am contemplating a small iOS project in which the most natural user interface is probably for the user to drag symbols from a "well" at the bottom of the screen onto targets at the top of the screen. Conventionally, one would expect to see the symbols, perhaps with high transparency or as outlines, accompany the drag, and some sort of feedback from the symbol or the target when the target is reached.

I don't see any built-in classes for handling this in Cocoa Touch, but it seems like a very common sort of interface and I bet there are established best practices and/or libraries for handling it. Can anybody offer me any pointers?

Comment: @Eric D. Ultimately cross-platform, but for the moment let's assume Cocoa Touch. I'll correct my sloppiness on that point above.

Comment: why not use UIKit for this? There are built in functions

Comment: @Wraithseeker I'm new to these libraries; which functions should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

There's a great [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/44270/sprite-kit-tutorial-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites) built some time ago regarding touch motions and in your case drag and drop.

The relevant functions are under the [UIResponderClass](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html) under Responding to Touch Events.